Transformer from Scratch can not make inference
I'm coding a Transformer base on this Github link but when the training process was already done, it can only infer the  characters and nothing else while testing.
I will describe what i had done so far here.
I choose this dataset from Kaggle. It's a pair of file train.en contains english sentences and train.vi contains vietnamese sentences.
Firstly, i go through 2 files to create 2 dictionaries (index : word) for 2 language.
Then, i set MAX_LENGTH = 300 and change all sentences of both file into 300-dimension vectors.
This is my code:
SOS = 1
EOS = 0

class Language:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.word2idx = {}
        self.idx2word = {1: 'SOS', 0: 'EOS'}
        self.word2count = {}
        self.n_words = 2
    
    def addWord(self, word):
        word = word.replace('.', '')
        if word not in self.word2idx:
            self.idx2word[self.n_words] = word
            self.word2idx[word] = self.n_words
            self.n_words += 1
            self.word2count[word] = 1
        else:
            self.word2count[word] += 1
        return self.idx2word[self.n_words-1], self.word2idx[word], self.word2count[word]
            
    def addSentence(self, sentence):
        sentence = sentence.strip().replace('  ', ' ')
        return [self.addWord(word) for word in sentence.split()]
    
    def addManySentences(self, many_sentences):
        return [self.addSentence(sentence) for sentence in many_sentences]
    
    def sentence2vector(self, sentence, pretrain=None):
        sentence = sentence.replace('.', '')
        vector = []
        for word in sentence.split():
            if pretrain != None:
                if word in pretrain:
                    vector.append(pretrain.key_to_index[word])
                else:
                    vector.append(0)
            else:
                if word in self.word2idx:
                    vector.append(self.word2idx[word])
                else:
                    vector.append(0)
        vector.append(EOS)
        return vector
    
    def vector2sequence(self, vector, pretrain=None):
        words = []
        for idx in vector:
            if pretrain != None:
                words.append(pretrain.index_to_key[idx])
            else:
                words.append(self.idx2word[idx])
        words.append('EOS.')
        sequence = ' '.join(words).replace('SOS ', '').replace(' EOS', '')
        return sequence
    
    def manyVector2manySequece(self, manyVector, pretrain=None):
        return [self.vector2sequence(vector, pretrain) for vector in manyVector]

inputs = []
with open('/kaggle/input/train-vi-en/train.en', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().strip().split('\n')
    for line in lines:
        line = '\t'.join(line.split('\t')[:2])
        for p in string.punctuation:
            if p != "'" and p in line:
                line = line.replace(p, f'')
        inputs.append(line)
inputs = np.array(inputs)
        
targets = []
with open('/kaggle/input/train-vi-en/train.vi', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().strip().split('\n')
    for line in lines:
        line = '\t'.join(line.split('\t')[:2])
        for p in string.punctuation:
            if p != "'" and p in line:
                line = line.replace(p, f'')
        targets.append(line)
targets = np.array(targets)

eng = Language('english')
eng.addManySentences(inputs)

vie = Language('vietnamese')
vie.addManySentences(targets)

num_seq = len(inputs)

input_matrix = torch.zeros((num_seq, MAX_LENGTH), dtype=torch.int)
for idx in range(num_seq):
    vector = eng.sentence2vector(inputs[idx])
    end_pos = min(MAX_LENGTH, len(vector))
    input_matrix[idx, :end_pos] = torch.tensor(vector)[:end_pos]
    
target_matrix = torch.zeros((num_seq, MAX_LENGTH), dtype=torch.int)
for idx in range(num_seq):
    vector = vie.sentence2vector(targets[idx])
    end_pos = min(MAX_LENGTH, len(vector))
    target_matrix[idx, :end_pos] = torch.tensor(vector)[:end_pos]

Finally, i split it to trainset, testset and validset and use them to create torch DataLoader.
This is my Transformer code:
def padding_mask(tensor, device='cpu'):
    # Padding mask để lọc ra mấy cái kiểu sos, eos mà ta thêm vào, vốn vô nghĩa
    return 1 - (tensor == 0).to(torch.int).to(device)

def lookahead_mask(tensor, device='cpu'):
    # Look-ahead mask để cho việc chỉ nhìn vào những từ ở đằng trước trong self-attention
    sq_len = tensor.shape[-1]
    return torch.ones(sq_len, sq_len).tril().to(device)

class Transformer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size, n_heads, ffw_hidden, n_encoders=1, n_decoders=1, dropout=0.5, device='cpu'):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.device = device
        self.output_size = output_size
        
        self.encoder = Encoder(input_size, hidden_size, n_heads, ffw_hidden, n_encoders, dropout, device=device)
        self.decoder = Decoder(hidden_size, output_size, n_heads, ffw_hidden, n_decoders, dropout, device=device)
        
        self.linear = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
        self.softmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=-1)
        
    def forward(self, input_tensor, target_tensor):
        encoder_mask = self.createEncoderMask(input_tensor)
        decoder_mask = self.createDecoderMask(target_tensor)
        
        encoder_output = self.encoder(input_tensor, encoder_mask)
        decoder_output = self.decoder(encoder_output, target_tensor, decoder_mask)
        out = self.softmax(self.linear(decoder_output))
        return out
    
    def createEncoderMask(self, encoder_input):
        return padding_mask(encoder_input, device=self.device).unsqueeze(1)
    
    def createDecoderMask(self, decoder_input):
        padding = padding_mask(decoder_input, device=self.device)
        lookahead = lookahead_mask(decoder_input, device=self.device)
        
        mask = torch.Tensor().to(self.device)
        for pad in padding:
            mask = torch.concat([mask, torch.min(pad, lookahead).unsqueeze(0)], dim=0)
        return mask
    
    def translate(self, x):
        x = x.squeeze().unsqueeze(0)
        target_tensor = torch.full(x.shape, EOS, device=self.device)
        return self.forward(x, target_tensor)

class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, embedding_dim, n_heads, ffw_hidden, n_encoders=1, dropout=0.1, device='cpu'):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(input_size, embedding_dim, device=device)
        self.PE = PositionalEncoding(embedding_dim, MAX_LENGTH, device=device)
        
        self.list_encoder_layers = nn.ModuleList([EncoderLayer(embedding_dim, n_heads, ffw_hidden, dropout=dropout) for _ in range(n_encoders)])
        
    def forward(self, input_tensor, mask=None):
        embedded = self.embedding(input_tensor)
        PE = self.PE(input_tensor)
        
        tensor = embedded + PE
        for layer in self.list_encoder_layers:
            tensor = layer(tensor, mask=mask)
        return tensor
    
class EncoderLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, n_heads, ffw_hidden, dropout=0.1):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.attention = MultiHeadAttention(input_size, n_heads)
        self.norm1 = Norm(input_size)
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        
        self.ffw = FeedForward(input_size, ffw_hidden)
        self.norm2 = Norm(input_size)
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        
    def forward(self, X, mask=None):
        _X = torch.clone(X)
        X = self.attention(X, X, X, mask=mask)
        X = self.norm1(self.dropout1(X + _X))
        
        _X = torch.clone(X)
        X = self.ffw(X)
        X = self.norm2(self.dropout2(X + _X))
        return X

class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embedding_dim, output_size, n_heads, ffw_hidden, n_decoders=1, dropout=0.1, device='cpu'):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(output_size, embedding_dim, device=device)
        self.PE = PositionalEncoding(embedding_dim, MAX_LENGTH, device=device)
        
        self.list_decoder_layers = nn.ModuleList([DecoderLayer(embedding_dim, n_heads, ffw_hidden, dropout=dropout) for _ in range(n_decoders)])
        
    def forward(self, encoder_output, target_tensor, mask=None):
        embedded = self.embedding(target_tensor)
        PE = self.PE(target_tensor)
        
        X = embedded + PE
        for layer in self.list_decoder_layers:
            X = layer(encoder_output, X, mask=mask)
        return X
    
class DecoderLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, n_heads, ffw_hidden, dropout=0.1):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.attention1 = MultiHeadAttention(input_size, n_heads)
        self.norm1 = Norm(input_size)
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        
        self.attention2 = MultiHeadAttention(input_size, n_heads)
        self.norm2 = Norm(input_size)
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        
        self.ffw = FeedForward(input_size, ffw_hidden)
        self.norm3 = Norm(input_size)
        self.dropout3 = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        
    def forward(self, encoder_output, X, mask=None):
        _X = torch.clone(X)
        X = self.attention1(X, X, X, mask=mask)
        X = self.norm1(self.dropout1(X + _X))
        
        _X = torch.clone(X)
        X = self.attention2(X, encoder_output, encoder_output, mask=mask)
        X = self.norm2(self.dropout2(X + _X))
        
        _X = torch.clone(X)
        X = self.ffw(X)
        X = self.norm3(self.dropout3(X + _X))
        return X

class PositionalEncoding(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embedding_dim, max_length, device):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.embedding_dim = embedding_dim
        self.device = device
        
        embedding = torch.zeros(max_length, self.embedding_dim, device=self.device)
        
        pos = torch.arange(0, max_length, device=self.device).float().unsqueeze(dim=1)
        i = torch.arange(0, self.embedding_dim, device=self.device)
        
        embedding[:, 0::2] = torch.sin(pos / (10000 ** (i[0::2] / self.embedding_dim)))
        embedding[:, 1::2] = torch.cos(pos / (10000 ** ((i[1::2]-1) / self.embedding_dim)))
        
        self.embed = nn.Parameter(embedding)
        
    def forward(self, X):
        seq_length = X.shape[-1]
        
        return self.embed[:seq_length]

class MultiHeadAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, n_heads):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.n_heads = n_heads
        
        self.lv = nn.Linear(input_size, input_size)
        self.lk = nn.Linear(input_size, input_size)
        self.lq = nn.Linear(input_size, input_size)
        
        self.attention = ScaledDotProductAttention()
        
        self.l_concat = nn.Linear(input_size, input_size)
        
    def forward(self, q, k, v, mask=None):
        q, k, v = self.lq(q), self.lk(k), self.lv(v)
        q, k, v = self.split(q), self.split(k), self.split(v)
        out = self.attention(q, k, v, mask=mask)
        
        out = self.concat(out)
        out = self.l_concat(out)
        
        return out
    
    def split(self, tensor):
        batch_size, length, input_size = tensor.shape
        
        head_size = input_size // self.n_heads
        
        tensor = tensor.view(batch_size, length, self.n_heads, head_size).transpose(-2, -3)
        return tensor
    
    def concat(self, tensor):
        batch_size, n_heads, length, head_size = tensor.shape
        
        input_size = n_heads * head_size
        
        tensor = tensor.transpose(-2, -3).contiguous().view(batch_size, length, input_size)
        return tensor
    
class ScaledDotProductAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
    def forward(self, q, k, v, mask=None):
        dk = k.shape[-1]
        k_t = k.transpose(-1, -2)
        
        matmulqk = q @ k_t
        scale = matmulqk / math.sqrt(dk)
        
        if mask is not None:
            for batch in range(scale.shape[0]):
                for head in range(scale.shape[1]):
                    scale[batch, head] = scale[batch, head].masked_fill(mask[batch] == 0, -1e9)
            
        softmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=-1)(scale)
        
        matmul = softmax @ v
        return matmul

class Norm(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, eps=1e-7):
        super().__init__()
        self.gamma = nn.Parameter(torch.ones(input_size))
        self.beta = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(input_size))
        self.eps = eps
        
    def forward(self, x):
        mean = x.mean(-1, keepdim=True)
        var = x.var(-1, unbiased=False, keepdim=True)
        
        out = (x - mean) / torch.sqrt(var + self.eps)
        out = self.gamma * out + self.beta
        return out

class FeedForward(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, dropout=0.1):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.ln1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.ln2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, input_size)
        
    def forward(self, X):
        X = self.ln1(X)
        X = self.relu(X)
        X = self.dropout(X)
        X = self.ln2(X)
        return X

This is my train function:
def train(train_loader, model, n_epochs, criterion, learning_rate=0.001, print_every=100, device='cpu'):
    print_loss_total = 0
    
    model = model.to(device)

    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
    criterion = criterion

    for epoch in range(1, n_epochs + 1):
        total_loss = 0
        for input_tensor, target_tensor in train_loader:
            input_tensor = input_tensor.to(device)
            target_tensor = target_tensor.to(device)

            optimizer.zero_grad()

            outputs = model(input_tensor, target_tensor)
            
            loss = criterion(
                outputs.view(-1, outputs.size(-1)),
                target_tensor.view(-1).long()
            )
            loss.backward()

            optimizer.step()
            
            del input_tensor
            del target_tensor
            torch.cuda.empty_cache()

            total_loss += loss.item()

        print_loss_total += total_loss / len(train_loader)

        if epoch % print_every == 0:
            print_loss_avg = print_loss_total / print_every
            print_loss_total = 0
            print(f'At {epoch}, loss is {print_loss_avg}')

And when i just use the trainset to test, an unexpexted error occur:
words = []
for input_tensor, target_tensor in train_loader:
    input_tensor = input_tensor.to(device)[:1]
    target_tensor = target_tensor.to(device)[:1]
    
    print('Eng: ', eng.manyVector2manySequece(input_tensor.cpu().numpy()))
    print('Vie: ', vie.manyVector2manySequece(target_tensor.cpu().numpy()))
    
    en_mask = model.createEncoderMask(input_tensor)
    en_output = model.encoder(input_tensor, mask=en_mask)
    
    pred_tensor = torch.randint(1, output_size, (1, MAX_LENGTH), device=device)
    pred_tensor[0, 0] = SOS
    for i in range(2, MAX_LENGTH+1):
        de_input = pred_tensor[:, :i]
        en_out = en_output[:, :i]
        de_mask = model.createDecoderMask(de_input)
        de_output = model.decoder(en_out, de_input, de_mask)
        out = model.softmax(model.linear(de_output)).topk(1)[-1]
    print(out)
    break

The result of out is full of zeros.
I have tried to change the size of dataset but nothing change.
I have use full code from the Github link which i'm base on but it requires torchtext==0.6 and Kaggle got error while i try to pip install it.
I change the criterion at train, raise the batch_size, raise number of epochs, change the learning rate. That's all of solution a can figure but nothing can change the result that my Transformer can only predict a full-zero vector from train data.
I haven't known where is wrong so far.
Anyone help me!
